# Xubuntu 12.04: Slow Login

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, xubuntu

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04, and after I ran the update, my login started slowing down big time. I've dabbled a little bit with the programs in Settings -> Settings Manager -> Session and Startup, and tried closing and opening these programs, and then rebooting.

Anyways, I narrowed it down to a combination of 2 processes, "Network" (the connection manager) and "Xfce Volume Daemon". Their corresponding terminal commands are:

```
~$ nm-applet
~$ xfce4-volumed
```

If I disable them, and then run them after login is complete, everything works just fine. Is there a way for me to run these commands automatically at start up? I want to maybe write a shell script and save it somewhere, or at least edit the order things happen after login, so the desktop can load before these processes.

Hope I've been clear enough, and thanks in advance!

NAX

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question

Comment: [ubuntu.se] is an even better one :)

Comment: Or [SU] comes to mind